# Leisure/single long-visit visa Dubai

Tags: abu-dhabi

I'm in Abu Dhabi, UAE, on a visit visa. It was written in my visa the area is Dubai. I got a job in Abu Dhabi since I entered in this area of the UAE and they applied 3 times for a work visa. It was always rejected. Is it not possible to work here or not possible to be issued a work visa if I'm on a leisure/single long-visit visa?

Comment: I think you have to exit the country before applying for a new visa. Do they tell the reason for rejection?

Comment: @newton 1st rejection reason is I have double visa and we already cleared it to the immigration 2nd is fawri 3rd is double visa again but I have only 1 visa.

Answer (score 3):

Going from Dubai to Abu Dhabi is fine on a UAE visa because they are both constituent parts of the UAE, **However it is certainly forbidden to work in the UAE on a tourist visa**. If i remember correctly it must also be annotated on the Visa itself.

However you can apply for work permit while you are in UAE on a tourist visa and if granted, your status will be updated.

> Visitors and tourists should be aware that it is illegal to work in the UAE while being on a visit or tourist visa. According to the UAE's labour and residency laws, a person cannot work if he has not been issued a work permit and employment visa. Violators may be liable to fines and deportation.
>
> Under the Ministerial Resolution No. 377 of 2014, holders of all types of visas can modify the status of their entry while staying in the country. Applicant must do this before the expiry of his current visa to avoid any penalties.
>
> People will be able to amend the status of their entry permits electronically through a few quick steps.

Source: [The Official Portal of UAE Government](https://government.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/visa-provisions)

> I got a job in Abu Dhabi since I entered in this area of the UAE and they applied 3 times for a work visa.

Unfortunately that's the only option. If your employer is unable to get a permit for you then you can not legally work. After 3 failed attempts it is probably time to get an Immigration Lawyer on the case.

Comment: They re apply me in dubai is it possible that it could be approve since they have a different system